# ignore spaces and count only alphabets

Tags: java

can you please give an idea for our program to ignore spaces and count only alphabets is even small other wise caps

```
public class evennumbersloop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Hello World uuuu iii pppp jjj";

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++) {

            if (str.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    String str1 = "";
                    str1 = str1 + str.charAt(count);
                    System.out.print(str1.toUpperCase());
                } else {
                    System.out.print(str.charAt(count));
                }

                count++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Could you [edit] your question and clarify it? BTW `Character` class has many helpful methods like `Character.isLetter` (if that is what you mean by "alphabets").

Comment: Give an example of what you get and what you want ? What does `give an idea` mean ?

Comment: And what is the problem with what you have ? Can you clarify this please ? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To count only alphabets you can use a regular expression and code something like below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello World uuuu iii pppp jjj");
   int count = 0;
   while (matcher.find())
       count++;
   System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you mean,

```
String str = "Hello World uuuu iii pppp jjj";
```

ignore whitespaces and count number of alphabets present --> actually the length of string without whitespaces?

```
String str = "Hello World uuuu iii pppp jjj";
System.out.println("Length of string with spaces: "+str.length());
str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
System.out.println("Length of String without white spaces: "+str.length());
```

Output:

```
Length of string with spaces: 29
Length of String without white spaces: 24
```

Comment: And then try with `"Hello World\tThis is me!"` You should use `\s` at least to match every "blank" character.